# In Three.js is there a way to get a list of controllers attached to an object?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

In Three.js is there a way to get the list of controllers attached to an object?  Or at least a controller attached to the object.  I have a controller attached to an object.  I don't want the transformController to always be visible on that object.  I tried trnasformController.enabled = false however it seemed to do nothing.  I detached it and that seemed to work fine however if I click on the object I need a way to navigate back to the controllers that are attached to it.  Is there a way I can do this in order to detach it?  What I'm looking to do is only have the controller appear once the object is clicked on so it can be modified.  TIA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to attach the transform control when the object is selected.Then detach the transform control when Esc key pressed.

Javascript:

```
var renderer
var saphi_mesh
var control
var controls
var pickable = []

function init() {
    container = document.createElement("div")
    document.body.appendChild(container)



    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
    camera.position.z = 500
    camera.position.y = 50

    scene = new THREE.Scene()

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10, 0xff0000, 0xffffff);
    scene.add(gridXZ);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);

    // clone wont work ... seems to retain the same material
    var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xff1234
    }));
    cube1.position.y = 50;
    cube1.name = "cube1";

    scene.add(cube1);
    pickable.push(cube1);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    control = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    pickable.push(control);
    control.addEventListener('change', render);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousedown", onClick, false)
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keydown, false)
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    render()
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        scene.remove(control);
    }
}

function onClick(event) {
    x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    dir = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, -1)
    dir.unproject(camera)

    ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, dir.sub(camera.position).normalize())

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(pickable)
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var SELECTED = intersects[0].object;
        scene.add(control);
        control.attach(SELECTED);
    }
}

init()
animate()
```

Here is working sample of jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qZh59/3/

I hope this should help you,..

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume the sphere code in there is just left over code and not needed.